# Detailed difference between Procedural Programming and Object Oriented Programming

Tags: object-oriented, procedural

I'm a newbie. Please give me a detailed (very detailed one) about these two types of programming that even I, a beginner, could understand. Their core differences, relevant things that I must remember, things like that will be helpful.

Comment: Hi JasperC, the question, as it is written, is probably too broad for the Q&A format of this site, since it would require a whole essay for a decent answer. But you find plenty of answers and examples around this topic when you just enter "procedural object oriented" into the search box. [This one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263156/convert-procedural-code-to-object-oriented), for instance, gives a short example on OO vs Procedural code, which might be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In *Procedural Programming*, the primary method of abstraction, the primary unit of decomposition, the primary unit of behavior, the primary method of structuring your program (which also means the primary method of structuring your *thoughts*) is the *Procedure*.

In *Object-Oriented Programming*, the primary method of abstraction, the primary unit of decomposition, the primary unit of behavior, the primary method of structuring your program (which also means the primary method of structuring your *thoughts*) is the *Object*.

In Programming, you break your problem down into sub-problems, and then every sub-problem into sub-sub-problems, and every sub-sub-problem into sub-sub-sub-problems, and so on, until each and every sub-sub-sub-…-sub-sub-problem is so small and simple that it is easy to solve.

In Procedural Programming, every problem, sub-problem, sub-sub-problem, sub-sub-sub-problem, etc. corresponds to a Procedure, and the bigger problems are solved by Procedures calling each other.

In Object-Oriented Programming, every problem, sub-problem, sub-sub-problem, sub-sub-sub-problem, etc. corresponds to an Object, and the bigger problems are solved by Objects sending Messages to each other.

You can imagine each Object as like a tiny computer on the Internet. Each object has its own RAM that no other object can see (called *instance variables*, *instance fields*, or something like that, depending on the programming language). It also has its own code that no other object can see or call (called *implementation*, *`private` methods*, etc.) Just like Google cannot read your laptop's RAM or execute Word on your laptop.

*The only thing* another object can do, is *send a message* to the object. And *the only thing* another object can observe is the reply. The other object does not know *how* the receiver of the message came up with this reply.

If you want to understand more about Programming Paradigms, Peter van Roy made [this amazing poster that shows the 34 major paradigms and their relations and positions on various axis](http://WWW.Info.UCL.Ac.Be/~pvr/paradigms). He also wrote the article [*Programming Paradigms for Dummies: What Every Programmer Should Know*](http://WWW.Info.UCL.Ac.Be/~pvr/VanRoyChapter), which is targeted at musicians, and thus very approachable. And if you want the *full* treatment, [*Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming* by Peter Van Roy and Seif Haridi](http://WWW.Info.UCL.Ac.Be/~pvr/book) is the definitive book on Programming Paradigms.

If you are interested in understanding and learning Object-Oriented Programming, I would suggest starting with Smalltalk (for example using [Pharo](http://pharo.org/)), then moving to [Self](http://www.selflanguage.org/), then [Newspeak](https://newspeaklanguage.org/). After that, [Eiffel](https://www.eiffel.org/) (using the book [*Object-Oriented Software Construction* by Bertrand Meyer](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction%2C_2nd_Edition)) for a different take on Object-Oriented Programming, and lastly, [Scala](https://scala-lang.org/) (using the book [*Programming in Scala*](http://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_3ed)) for a very modern take.

For Procedural Programming, I would suggest Scheme, particularly Racket using the book [*How to Design Programs*](https://htdp.org/).

There is another important difference between Procedural Programming as it is typically implemented, and Object-Oriented Programming, and that is the way that *Data Abstraction* is performed.

In Object-Oriented Programming, the mechanism for Data Abstraction is (not surprisingly) Object-Oriented Data Abstraction. This essentially refers to Message Protocol, the internal representation of an object is hidden behind the Behavioral Interface (aka Protocol) formed by the Messages it understands and how it responds to those Messages.

In Procedural Programming, the mechanism for Data Abstraction is (typically) *Abstract Data Types*. With Abstract Data Types, the Abstraction is formed by the Type System.

One of the major differences between Object-Oriented Data Abstraction and Abstract Data Types is that two instances of the same Abstract Data Types have access to each other's internal representation, whereas an Object can *never* access another Object's internal representation *even if they are of the same type*.

A great explanation of this difference is given in [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/), which is *very* approachable.

Comment: It's worth noting that some messages sent do not result in a reply. They result in more messages sent to other objects.

Comment: "an Object can never access another Object's internal representation even if they are of the same type" - in most languages, you *most certainly can* access the internal representation of an object of the same concrete type, but you usually can't access different internal representations of different derivatives (subclasses) of the same abstraction (or if the language allows it, you generally can't rely on that).

Comment: With ADTs, one type encapsulates a finite number of different representations, and its functions can internally determine the concrete representation of an instance (this can be supported by a language mechanism), and rely on that; in a sense, even though client code is unaware of the concrete underlying type, unlike with objects, the representations themselves are a part of a narrow interface exposed to those writing extensions (new functions) for the ADT.

Comment: Correction: *wide interface (narrow being the public one meant for client code) - I just noticed the mistake, but can't edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers go into details about the differences, just as the OP requested. But since the question also asks for responses that even a  beginner could understand, going into too much details can risk loosing "the essence" of the difference. So just want to mention that.

Yes, it's true that in Procedural Programming everything is structured around procedures, while in OOP is structured around objects. **But the actual difference is how Data and Behavior go together.**

In Procedural Programming data and behavior are separate things. You create your programs as a set of procedures (i.e. instructions) and then "feed" data to those procedures.

In OOP the data and the behavior sit together. Grossly speaking, an object is just a bunch of data coupled with the instructions that operate on that data. In this context procedures are no longer fed data, they are "bound" to that data, so they now become "methods".

So first understand the basic difference ([see here for a short summary](http://ocw.utm.my/pluginfile.php/728/mod_resource/content/0/01PPvsOOP-edit15Feb13.pdf)) before going into more details. Just as one example of going into more details, static methods in OOP are not bound to objects (unless you consider the class itself as an object and not just a "template" for creating objects) and they can very easily be abused to allow for full procedural programming in an Object Oriented language. And then it's easy to fall trap to many discussions that say that static methods are good or bad, and the essential difference becomes blurred.

Answer (score 0):

On basic level software is a list of atomic instructions that the computer executes one after the other.

Writing and understanding long lists of these instructions is more complex than most of us programmers can handle.  Therefore we programmers introduced paradigms (such as procedural programming, object oriented, and functional programming) that help us organize and cope with long lists of instructions.  The paradigms often come with restrictions we impose upon ourselves and in return we can view the long lists of instructions organized in a way that is closer to our human/cultural/personal way of thinking.  Both procedural programming and object oriented programming are programming paradigms.

In procedural programming we restrict ourselves in:

- how we may instruct the computer to jump through the list of instructions
- how the computer interprets bytes/words in memory:
  a word is either data, which can be read and written, or an instruction which can be executed.

Jumping is restricted to jumping only to the beginning of a procedure, a function call, and at the end of every procedure we return to the instruction right after the corresponding call.

The restrictions of procedural programming give us that the long is now divided into procedures and sub procedures.  A procedure is a list of conceptual steps, not necessarily atomic computer instructions, to solve our problem.  The software becomes a tree of procedures.  The root procedure (main) solves our problem.  Main calls other procedures to solve parts of the problem; these procedures call other procedures.
We can partially ignore the implementation details of sub procedures when working on a procedure.
And, due to the restriction on where jumps can go, we gain that we know is what state we can expect the procedure's local data to be in.

In the paradigm of object oriented programming we have the restrictions of procedural programming, on jumping and on the interpretation of bytes as data or instructions, and the additional restrictions:

- we group data and procedures, now called methods, into objects/classes;
- we restrict which methods may call which other methods and may read and write which data, this is called encapsulation; and,
- there should be no global data not contained in objects.

These restrictions give us:

- that we can view the software as a collection of things (objects) that communicate by sending messages (invoking methods) fitting to the worldview, of some of us, that the world consists of things that interact;
- we know in what state we can expect all data;
- we can ignore the implementation details of other objects and private method; and,
- we can use one object implementation in place of an other object implementation.

Concluding, procedural programming and object oriented programming are both programming paradigms.  With both we place some restrictions upon ourselves.  Object oriented programming has additional restrictions: group data and methods into objects/classes and encapsulation.  Both provide a different view of the low level list of instructions aiming to be more inline with our way of thinking: a procedure of steps (calls to sub procedures) to complete a task; a collection of interacting objects.